# catkin_make do not create header files for srv files!

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, service, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxVQnWhDgfg

I tried this tutorial. This tutorial is about creating srv files. I did everything like tutorial showed me. But in 4:14 tutorial says "you can verify your header files in devel/include" . For me this include file was not created.

I used catkin_make for compiling the workspace.

I did not understand problem. Anyone can help?

You can look my files here:   https://github.com/MYComodo/ROS_Tutorials

I am trying to do service_tut  package. In this package i created srv file. I want to use for learn how to write a service/client example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342679/catkin_make-do-not-create-header-files-for-srv-files!/) by [KOMODO](https://answers.ros.org/users/45642/komodo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the headers of messages and services to be generated, the `generate_messages` macro needs to be invoked in CMake. It's currently [commented out](https://github.com/MYComodo/ROS_Tutorials/blob/9ca3b7bdd21a3b4f658f39b2ea2834efc457c959/src/service_tut/CMakeLists.txt#L73)

As a side note, there is an [official tutorial on the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) that will walk you through it with copy-n-paste able instructions.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KOMODO](https://answers.ros.org/users/45642/komodo/) on 2020-01-30**:
thanks for responding. It worked.

Merci beaucoup pour l'aide :)

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-01-30**:
Avec plaisir :)